# Database left outer join with a base table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables A, B, C with the data as follows

Table A

```
C1     C2
----------
100     X
200     Y
300     z
```

Table B

```
C1     C2
-----------
100    bb
300    bb1
```

Table C

```
C1     C2
-----------
200    cc
300    cc1
```

I want a query which can out put as follows; The count of records in the result should be same as the count of records in A.

```
100   X      100   bb    null null
200   y      null  null  200  cc
300   z      300   bb1   300  cc1
```

Note: All the tables have one-one relationship and 3 tables are just given for example. This can be any number of tables.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How did that attempt not work as you desired?  What part of the problem is giving you difficulty?

Comment: You may need to add column labels to that results table.  Where do all those 100s and 200s come from?

Comment: What is your RDMS?

Comment: This requirement is the **most basic** of `left outer join`. Just [read it here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) and you will find it **very easy** to write the query you want in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.c1 = b.c1
LEFT JOIN tableC c ON a.c1 = c.c1
```

Comment: **IMO** this is not the way to help him. It's more harmful than helpful to feed him like this

Comment: Agreed, i don't want to be fed either. I tried left outer join and the reason why i was confused was that the counts do not match, but found that i am hitting the OLTP database and the counts keep changing. I was kind of misled..my bad whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

try this, should work -

```
SELECT res.x,
  res.y,
  res.z,
  res.w,
  c.c1,
  c.c2
FROM
  (SELECT a.c1 x, a.c2 y, b.c1 z, b.c2 w FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.c1=b.c1
  ) res
FULL OUTER JOIN c
ON res.x=c.c1
ORDER BY res.x;
```